Problem with client and server operation on ZeroMQ pattern ROUTER-DEALER
I want to make a connection between the client and the server in my C++ application in Linux.
On the client, I use a DEALER socket.
On the server, I use proxies and workers to asynchronously process messages from the client. In the workers, I again use a DEALER socket.
Messages from the Client arrive at the Server, but the Server is blocked and does not respond to messages. I think I have the wrong message structure for the sockets I am using.
Help me correctly create a message on the client side, and also correctly create a response on the server side.
// Client
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Client {
public:
    Client(const std::string& address) 
        : context(1), socket(context, zmq::socket_type::dealer) {
        socket.connect(address);
    }

    void sendRequest(const std::string& request_data) {
        zmq::message_t request(request_data.size());
        memcpy(request.data(), request_data.data(), request_data.size());

        socket.send(request, zmq::send_flags::none);

        zmq::message_t reply;
        socket.recv(reply, zmq::recv_flags::none);

        std::string reply_data(static_cast<char*>(reply.data()), reply.size());
        std::cout << "Received reply: " << reply_data << std::endl;
    }

private:
    zmq::context_t context;
    zmq::socket_t socket;
};



// Server
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

class Worker {
public:
    Worker(zmq::context_t& context) : worker_socket(context, zmq::socket_type::dealer) {
        worker_socket.connect("inproc://workers");
    }

    void process() {
        while (true) {
            zmq::message_t client_id;
            zmq::message_t empty_frame;
            zmq::message_t request;

            // Receive the client ID, an empty frame and a message
            worker_socket.recv(client_id, zmq::recv_flags::none);
            worker_socket.recv(empty_frame, zmq::recv_flags::none);
            worker_socket.recv(request, zmq::recv_flags::none);

            // Process the request and prepare a response
            std::string response_data = "Response: " + std::string(static_cast<char*>(request.data()), request.size());

            // We send to the client: client identifier, empty frame, and response message
            worker_socket.send(client_id, zmq::send_flags::sndmore);
            worker_socket.send(empty_frame, zmq::send_flags::sndmore);
            worker_socket.send(zmq::buffer(response_data), zmq::send_flags::none);
        }
    }

private:
    zmq::socket_t worker_socket;
};

class Server {
public:
    Server() : context(1), frontend(context, zmq::socket_type::router), backend(context, zmq::socket_type::dealer) {
        frontend.bind("tcp://*:5555");
        backend.bind("inproc://workers");

        // Create and launch workers
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            workers.emplace_back([this]() {
                Worker worker(context);
                worker.process();
            });
        }
    }

    void run() {
        zmq::proxy(frontend, backend);  // Launch a proxy for routing between frontend and backend
    }

    ~Server() {
        for (auto& worker : workers) {
            if (worker.joinable())
                worker.join();
        }
    }

private:
    zmq::context_t context;
    zmq::socket_t frontend;
    zmq::socket_t backend;
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
};


